# Solve expressions and display on webpage

Tags: html, boolean-logic

I am very confused with a question. Question below

[image]

What is the circle and inside plus sign? and what type of expression is this? Is this any kind of Boolean algebra Or logic gates? Can anyone help how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Which gate it is

That circle with a plus sign i.e ⊕, is known as Exclusive OR gate. It is an OPERATION of OR gate.

#### Value for this Gate

Its value is true, if either one is true and the second is false. If both of the inputs are true of both are false, its false.

#### Truth Table for this gate

```
X | Y | Result
0   0   0
1   0   1
0   1   1
1   1   0
```

This is the truth table for it.

#### Your Equation

```
(x+y)⊕y
```

First solve out the paranthesis part. Then use the result as `x` and you have the `y` on the right side of the operator. Now, check in the table for the value :) You'll get the answer. If both are true, the answer would be false, it either one is false and other is true then the result would be true. From the Truth Table of the GATE.

#### Reference

For more on that refer the link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate

Comment: How can i solve it? I mean what is the method to solve it? Should i solve it like algebra equation or there is another method?

Comment: How you created that table? can you refer a link to read how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, Just go to the WikiPedia page, and secondly. I have explained how the value would be zero or one, :)

Comment: What is" Solve Expressions and write all steps in this HTML Page " What should i write in steps? Or just solution of it are the steps?

Comment: Yup! the solution along with some explaination or description would do it. :) thats all you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

In Boolean Algebra:

`+` represents OR

`.` represents AND

`⊕` represents Exclusive OR (a.k.a. XOR)

---

An **OR** is `true` if one of its operands is true.

And **AND** is `true` if both its operands are true.

And **XOR** is true if one of its operands is true, but not both.